# finding the sum of a sequence with sign of terms reversed

Tags: math, number-theory

Let there be a set of N natural numbers 1,2,3,4...N. We are allowed to insert + or − sign in front of each number and add all the resultant numbers. The minimum non-­negative value obtained is denoted as D(N).

Find the value of D(1)+D(2)+...+D(19216812112)

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Is this homework, or perhaps from a programming contest? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't think this is a programming assignment.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose D(i) = 0 for some i. Then you can know that D(i + 4) = 0 as well. Why? What do you know about D(i + 1), D(i + 2) or D(i + 3)? How can this help you answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

if sum of the numbers 1,2,3,..upto n is even then D(n)=0 otherwise 1 that is sum=n*(n+1)/2;for the sum to be even either n is divisible by 4 or is (n+1);so D(n)=0 for n=0 or 3 mod 4; 1 otherwise so the pattern followed by D(1)+D(2)+...+D(N) is 1100110011001100....